# How do I store items into array outside the while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
Scanner fileInput;  // inventory file
int counter=0;
File inFile = new File("inventory.dat");
try 
{
    fileInput = new Scanner(inFile);// open inventory file and read

    while (fileInput.hasNext())
    {

        GroceryItem grocery= new GroceryItem();
        grocery.readItem(fileInput);
        //System.out.println(item1);
        inventory[counter]=grocery;


        //item1.printInventory(inventory,counter);
        total=counter;
        counter++;

    }

}

catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error: inventory.dat not found"); 

}
```

I'm trying to print the inventory array outside of the while loop in the `try....catch` block, but everytime I do that, all of the elements in the inventory array get replaced with the last item of `item1`.

If I stay inside the `while` loop, everything works fine.

Comment: I think we need to see the code for `grocery.readItem(fileInput);`

Comment: that part of the code just reads in a string, then that string is supposed to get stored in inventory array, but it keeps getting over written by the last item in the inventory arrray.

Comment: I don't know what's going on, but you need to provide enough code for us to reproduce the problem, otherwise it's impossible to help. I could be wrong, but I don't think the error is in the code we can see.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot put a comment yet, so I'll answer here.

In my opnion, according to the snippet that you put, if you call outside of the while:

```
item1.printInventory(inventory,counter);
```

Will not this only print the last one element?
Because you are using the counter that is in the last position, and the inventory array.

to print all the inventory outside the while, you need a method:

```
item1.printInventory(inventory);


//The Method in the class of item1
private void printInventory(GroceryItem[] inventory) {
    for (GroceryItem item: inventory) {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

That's what you want?